# Problem/bug with a listview

Tags: android, listview

I just want to store a data in a listview then displaying it with a textview, i identified the problem, it's in fact this ligne:

```
data = date + " : " + y + "L/100KM\n"+ " " + value1 + "L "+ value2 + "KM\n";
```

Operations made:
1-if i delete the first or the second "\n" the listview indicates that there is not any datas to display.
2- if i let the two "\n" then the value1 and value2 are not displayed !

The oncreate function of the class that show the datas:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.histo);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    activity = this;
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
    fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
    s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir + fileName);

    updatelv(this);
    ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    L.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

the code when tapping the calculate button in the main class:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast.makeText(carburant.this, "Bienvenue!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    data = "";


  final EditText vol;
  final EditText kil;
  final EditText cons;

  vol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volume2);
  kil= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kilometrage2);
  cons= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.consom2);

 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String value1 = (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.volume2))
                .getText()).toString();
        String value2 = (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.kilometrage2)).getText())
                .toString();

  if (value1 .equalsIgnoreCase("") && value2.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      {
      Toast.makeText(carburant.this, "Veuillez vérifier les deux champs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
  else{
                              float q1=Float.parseFloat(vol.getText().toString());
                              float q2=Float.parseFloat(kil.getText().toString());
                              float x=((q1 / q2)* 100);
                              String y= Float.toString(x);
                              cons.setText(y);

                              SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                              String date = format.format(new Date());
                              data = date + " : " + y + "L/100KM\n"+ " " + value1 + "L "+ value2 + "KM\n";

      if (data != "" ) {
          SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
       String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
       String fileDir = ""+ preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
       myIO.WriteSettings(context, fileDir + fileName, data);
       data = "";
```

The list_item XML:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" >
```

Histo.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/ViewHisto">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.XML:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/volume1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Volume(en Litres):">
   </TextView>
   <EditText android:id="@+id/volume2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp"
      android:numeric="integer|decimal"
      android:hint="@string/vol"
      >

   </EditText>




   <TextView android:id="@+id/kilometrage1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Kilometrage(en Kilomètres) :">
   </TextView>

   <EditText android:id="@+id/kilometrage2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp"
      android:numeric="integer|decimal"
      android:hint="@string/kil">

   </EditText>




   <TextView android:id="@+id/consom1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Consommation moyenne(en Litres/100KM) :">
   </TextView>
   <EditText android:id="@+id/consom2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp"
      android:numeric="integer|decimal"
      android:hint="@string/cons">
   </EditText> 


  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:text="Calculer" 
    android:id="@+id/button" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>
<Button
    android:text="Reset" 
    android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="280px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
 </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i really don't understand what you mean :\ ! well if you want i put the code... :\

Comment: @Matthew Willis: Sorry but can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider creating a View to through an Adapter containing two TextViews to you display it correctly? It's the best approach.

Comment: Yes, i made this: ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
  L.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, s[0]));

Comment: Post your Adapter, you should do it on getView.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: Please see my answer.

Comment: Can you post the xml layout for list_item ?  I suspect there is something about the settings on your text view that is causing this display issue.  In other words, the text is correctly set in the view, but the way it is displaying is wrapping or clipping.

Comment: @slund: please look at the first post i added the list_item XML file.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: how can i create "a View to through an Adapter containing two TextViews" ? Thanks :).

Comment: @slund: so no problem with the XML file ?

Comment: @androiniennn You do that writing a new Adapter, instead of using an ArrayAdapter. And, you don't post the code where you set the Adapter for the ListView.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: Million sorry but can you try to give me an example?

Comment: @andronienn - can you also post your main.xml?  I put a quick test together that just has a list view and the items all display as expected (all content shows).

Comment: @slund: please see the first post, i added the main.xml file .

Comment: @andronienn - well I still don't see anything that would cause what you are seeing. In addition, my simple test case is still working with your layout params. The only thing else I can suggest is that you double check the actual data in your array and adapter to make sure you are actually setting what you think you are.  Sorry I couldn't get to the root cause.

Comment: @slund: the data is well stored, the proof that when i put back the two "\n" all stored datas shows ! so you say that i make as Marcos said ? "You do that writing a new Adapter, instead of using an ArrayAdapter. And, you don't post the code where you set the Adapter for the ListView" ! but i really don't understand what he want tell :\!

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: can you provide please a link to make what you said ? Thanks.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: Well, i didn't understand anything :( ! anyway, thanks :).

Comment: Actually, I found this link on internet, I learned it though a book: "Android 2 Professional Developer"